# WCF comet and threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, comet, performance

I'm trying to use WCF to implement a comet style server push to an ajax web application.

In my WCF service, I've implemented a WaitForEvents method that calls Monitor.Wait to suspend the thread until new data arrives. At that point, the Monitor is pulsed, and the method returns the new data which closes the comet style request.

The request is made again when this happens.

Currently, this works fine but I noticed that WCF needs to create a new thread for each connected user. This is probably because the thread cannot be returned to the threadpool until data comes in, and so each connected user requires a new thread.

I want to make this implementation more efficient by having one thread service multiple connections. If I were to use a socket, this could be done by leaving the socket open and returning the thread to the thread pool first. When new data arrives, it will be delivered by another thread and we can write the new data directly to the socket and close it.

Does anybody know how this can be done via WCF?

I have been looking at "Push-Style Streaming" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb472551.aspx and they mention that "WCF implements a "pull" model in which the application code (the service) returns an instance of Stream and relies on the lower-level infrastructure to pull data from this stream and write it out to the network." but I cant find any examples of this one the website.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Check out [nComet](http://www.codeplex.com/ncomet)

It's not using WCF, but I believe the author is working on a version that uses WCF.  Contact him via codeplex and ask him :-)

> "nComet is a .NET implementation of
>   the Comet (reverse-AJAX push)
>   architecture. This server-side
>   pipeline uses long-lived
>   client-initiated HTTP connections to
>   push messages to the client. Once the
>   client receives a response, it
>   immediately opens another HTTP
>   request, which the server holds until
>   a message is ready. This architecture
>   allows the server to push dynamic
>   html/xml/json/etc to the browser,
>   rather than the browser polling the
>   server.
>
> This project is scoped to the .NET
>   server-side architecture, initially
>   providing a HttpListener (for a custom
>   host communicating with HTTP.SYS
>   directly) as well as a ASP.NET
>   implementation, where the ASP.NET
>   implementation can be hosted inside
>   IIS as well as an external process.
>   The library will simplify the
>   implementation of common message
>   patterns such as pushing the latest
>   data, as well as sync. Example code
>   and links to multiple client-side
>   javascript implementations will also
>   be provided."

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to check out [WebSync](http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync), a .NET comet implementation. Works just dandy with WCF.

(Disclaimer: I work for the company).